# Liveness probe failed: OCI runtime exec failed

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

I want to set a liveness probe. I am using a script to run a curl command. However i can see the liveness probe is failing with the following error:

**kubectl describe pod <>**

> Warning  Unhealthy  4m5s (x2 over 7m5s)  kubelet            Liveness
> probe failed: OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed:
> container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: exec format
> error: unknown
>
> Liveness:  exec [./livenessprobe.sh] delay=180s timeout=120s
> period=180s #success=1 #failure=2

**deployment.yaml**

```
        livenessProbe:
          exec:
            command:
            - ./livenessprobe.sh 
          initialDelaySeconds: 180 
          periodSeconds: 180
          timeoutSeconds: 120
          failureThreshold: 2
          successThreshold: 1
```

If i exec into the pod and run ./livenessprobe.sh i get the correct response. It is just a curl command

**./livenessprobe.sh**

```
curl --fail -H "Authorization: Basic <redacted>==" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "x-geeiq-origin: liveness-probe" -i -X POST -d @livenessprobe-request.json http://0.0.0.0:8080/
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to get this working by altering the command.

```
command:
- /bin/sh
- livenessprobe.sh
```